# Figure at the bottom of same page as another item

Tags: floats, positioning, exercises

I'm writing up lecture notes which include quick questions for the reader, together with upside-down answers at the bottom of the page.  The code I'm currently using for this has basically the following form:

```
\begin{question} % A custom theorem environment for the questions
Here's the question.
\end{question}

\begin{figure}[b]
\flushright \rotatebox{180}{Here's the answer.}
\end{figure}
```

The trouble is that if the question appears near the bottom of the page, there may not be room for the figure at the bottom, and the answer appears on the next page.  I'd prefer the question and answer always to appear on the same page, if necessary by inserting a page break before the question.  (Or at least, I think I'd prefer that -- I would like to see the effect and compare).

So that the comments make sense, here's the original version of my question, which I now realize wasn't properly getting at what I really want to do:

How can I force a figure to appear at the bottom of the same page (never the next page) where it's defined?

My question is almost a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173852/placing-the-floats-in-the-current-page-or-in-the-previous-page), in that an answer to my question would also be an answer to that one.  The difference is that I also don't want the figure to appear on the previous page, and it seems like the technical problems with doing that distracted anyone from addressing what I'd like to do here.

Comment: the answers given to the cited question *do* apply here.  you will have to place the figure input *after* the previous page has been filled, and early enough on the desired page that there is still enough space available for it to fit.  and in an extreme case, if this pushes the reference to the next page, you may have to do some rewriting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I think I'm missing something.  There are no answers given to the cited question.  Do you mean that the comments on that question imply that what I'm asking for is not possible to do globally?

Comment: yes, i did mean comments.  sorry for the confusion.  i don't think it's possible to do globally, since even one counterexample (which i described in my previous comment) tosses that hope out the window.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, you've helped me understand the comments on the other question better, and I realize now I should be asking a slightly different question.  I'll edit when I have a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression is that you want a footnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareNewFootnote{sol}[gobble]

\newcommand{\solution}[1]{%
  \footnotesol{\hspace*{-1.8em}\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{#1}}}%
}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Tell the result of doing $1+1$.\solution{$1+1=2$}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

(For producing the image I've artificially shortened the text height.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't aware of DeclareNewFootnote.  To simplify the question, I left out a few other aspects of what I'm doing, but it looks like I can probably modify your suggestion to do what I want.

Comment: Yes, a version of this does what I want.  I used `manyfoot` instead of `bigfoot`, since `bigfoot` introduced some other behaviors I didn't want and its documentation was too minimalist for me to figure out how to fix them.

Comment: Actually, no, this doesn't do what I want (although it does improve some behaviors, so for now I'm going with a version of this instead of what I used before).  It's still just as possible for a question and its answer to end up on different pages.

Comment: @MarkMeckes It shouldn't with `bigfoot`.

Comment: Yes, same issue with either `bigfoot` or `manyfoot`.

Comment: It is unfortunately quite difficult to come up with a MWE, since it depends so much on where the end of the page lands.

Comment: Okay, I've tracked down the problem.  It's not `bigfoot`'s fault, it's because of an incompatibility with something else I'm doing.  Maybe fodder for another question later on…  Anyway, I'm accepting this answer because it would solve the question I actually asked.